# Active record lookup - find_by_inventory_product_id is intermittently slow inspite of adding index

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3, indexing, rails-activerecord, unique-key

I have a simple new API endpoint, which involves querying my newly setup and populated table - inventory_products.

The schema of inventory_products table is :

```
CREATE TABLE `inventory_products` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `inventory_product_id` binary(16) DEFAULT NULL,
  `product_id` binary(16) DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` enum('ACTIVE','INACTIVE','DELETED') DEFAULT 'ACTIVE',
  `priority` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `inventory_service_id` tinyint(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `uc_inventory_product_id` (`inventory_product_id`),
  KEY `idx_product_status` (`product_id`,`status`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=76312817 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

The API endpoint mainly does the below:

```
def lookup_inventory_service_id
    return render_error_response(AUTH_ERROR, {status: 403}) unless client.name == PERMITTED_NAME

    ip_fetch_start = Time.now
    inventory_product = InventoryProducts.find_by_inventory_product_id(resource_attributes[:inventory_product_id])
    Rails.logger.info({inventory_product_id: resource_attributes[:inventory_product_id], inventory_product_fetch_time_ms: (Time.now - ip_fetch_start)*1000}.as_json)
    return head :not_found unless inventory_product
....
```

**Problem: The inventory_product lookup (find_by_inventory_product_id) is the standard function provided by Rails's ActiveRecord (I have not overwritten it in my model). This function takes from 10ms to sometimes even 650ms (found this from the logs I added). Why would this take up so much time in some cases and so less time in some other in spite of Mysql index existing on the column used in the lookup?**

I have mentioned inventory_product_id as a unique key in my schema and the MySQL query triggered by the above function is using inventory_product_id as an index from the below **explain** statement.

explain SELECT `inventory_products`.* FROM `inventory_products` WHERE `inventory_products`.`inventory_product_id` = 0x3a288cdce78d44618eadd72e240f26a4 LIMIT 1

id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  inventory_products  const   uc_inventory_product_id uc_inventory_product_id 17  const   1   NULL

**Is there something wrong in my schema? Do I explicitly need to mention inventory_product_id as a mysql index in the schema? Something like**:

`` KEY `idx_product_status` (`product_id`,`status`) ``

Thanks, in advance!!

I use Mysql 5.6 and rails - 3.2.8. Also, my rails application runs on a tomcat server (version - Apache Tomcat/7.0.16) inside jruby (1.7.0)/

Comment: Try adding `inventory_product_id` as an index and see how it goes.

Comment: If I am not wrong, the unique key constraint automatically creates an index right?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what *should* be happening:

The Optimizer will decide to use the Unique key.  This implies that there will be zero or one row with that value.

1. Drill down the BTree (3-4 levels deep) to find the index row for [inventory_product_id, id]
2. (assuming it found one row), use `id` to drill down the data BTree (probably 4 levels deep).
3. Extract all the columns of the row (since you said `SELECT *`).

Even on a very cold system, I would not expect more than 8 blocks would need to be read.  If the drives is HDD, then I would guestimate a max of 80ms to perform the query.  Meanwhile, I would say 10-20ms would be typical.

So...  630ms implies that *something else* is going on.  Especially suspect would be any query touching that table.

The `(product_id, status)` index is irrelevant to this query.

UUIDs are terrible for performance, especially when an index cannot fit in RAM.  How much *available* RAM do you have?  What is the value of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`?